# Extra space after Join Lines in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.1, 13.0.2 (but probably applies to earlier/later versions too)

Consider the following:

```
Collections.addAll(
    new ArrayList<Object>(), 
    new Object());
```

I do "Join Lines" since it will fit on one line:

```
Collections.addAll( new ArrayList<Object>(), new Object());
//                 ^ space is annoying      ^ space is nice
```

"Join Line" adds an extra space between the current and next line. It makes sense for some lines, but the space before the first parameter has always bugged me.

My workaround is to select and "Reformat Code", but I don't want to do the extra step if I don't have to.

**Is there a better way to make "Join Line" not add that first space?**

---

#### Notes:

Edit > Join Lines

- Mac OS X: <kbd>⌃⇧J</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Code > Reformat Code

- Mac OS X: <kbd>⌥⌘L</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: In Idea 133.471 (13.0.2 EAP) on Linux it works fine. Being anywhere in the first line CTRL-SHIFT-J creates `Collections.addAll(new ArrayList<Object>(),` and moves a cursor before new keyword. The same with old 13 BETA (133.124). I haven't spotted this problem before.

Comment: Did you try with the new configuration? Maybe you modified formatting in the past and forgot about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Code Style settings.

The bug appears—for both method declarations and calls—if you modify the Default Scheme and check the following settings:

```
Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces
    +- Method declaration parameters
    |   \- New line after '('
    \- Method call arguments
        \- New line after '('
```

Also, there needs to be more than one parameter in the method declaration or call.

[Here is the issue in JetBrains' YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120105).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a non default formatting set. Try:

`File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Spaces` and uncheck `Method call parantheses`.

Comment: In the `Before` section the following are unchecked: `Method call parentheses`, `Method declaration parentheses`. In the `Within` section, the following are unchecked: `Method call parentheses`. I thought it might have been a code style thing too, but then Reformat Code wouldn't remove that space.

Comment: Did you try with the new configuration (rename ~/.IntelliJIdea13 or ~/.IdeaIC13 to something else)?